# Origin of prenex normal form

Tags: logic, reference-request, math-history

I have managed to trace back Skolem's normal form to Skolem's "Logico-combinatorial investigations in the satisfiability or provability of mathematical propositions: A simplified proof of a theorem by L. Löwenheim and generalizations of the theorem".

What is the origin of prenex normal form?

Comment: Try also https://hsm.stackexchange.com/